Passing properties to an Inertia Vue page for Laravel Fortify's register view
I'm working on a web app that's using Laravel 10, Vue 3, and Inertia. (I'm new to all of these, btw) Laravel is using Fortify for a lot of features, including new user registration. I've been tasked with changing the registration page to display some things from the database. As far as I can tell, the usual approach to this would be to add some properties on the Vue page, and then populate those properties via Inertia somewhere in the Laravel app (e.g. a controller).
The challenge I'm encountering right now is that Fortify currently sets up the "register" view (implemented in the Jetstream service provider; see https://github.com/laravel/jetstream/blob/4.x/src/JetstreamServiceProvider.php#L210), pointing to the Auth/Register Vue page, but provides no way to add properties to the Inertia rendering (as far as I can tell).
So the questions are:

Is there a way to add properties in the existing configuration of Laravel, Fortify, Inertia, and Vue?
Can I safely just call Fortify::registerView() from a new service provider I make? Or will this cause some sort of conflict issue with the existing implementation done by the framework?
Do I have to (or would it be better to) extend something to override this default behavior? (I know Laravel allows me to extend a binding... https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/container#extending-bindings)
Would it be better to approach this from a completely different angle? Such as leaving the page as-is on the backend, and then setting up the page in Vue to make a subsequent request to fetch the necessary data from the database?


tl;dr: I can make my own call to Fortify::registerView() in app\Providers\JetstreamServiceProvider without issue.
I originally took the approach of making a subsequent ajax call using axios to fetch the necessary data for the Register page. However, I was tasked with adding yet another dynamic part to the Registration page, and I didn't want to have a pattern of making a bunch of ajax calls to populate portions of the page. With the help of Copilot, I found that I can make my own call to Fortify::registerView() in app\Providers\JetstreamServiceProvider and it will not conflict with the default implementation (linked to in my original question). In my case, my implementation looks like this (only including the applicable parts):
namespace App\Providers;

use App\Models\Plan;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Inertia\Inertia;
use Laravel\Fortify\Fortify;

class JetstreamServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot(): void
    {
        Fortify::registerView(function () {
            $plans = Plan::where('status', 1)->get();

            return Inertia::render('Auth/Register', [
                'plans' => $plans,
            ]);
        });
    }
}


Beginners should not jump straight into the Jetstream Inertia stack.
Start with the Breeze Blade stack.

HandleInertiaRequests middleware provides a way to pass shared data.
You can modify resources/js/Pages/Auth/Register.vue and app/Actions/Fortify/CreateNewUser.php copied to your project as you like.

This is more a comment than an answer

Unfortunately I don't have a choice as far as what I get to learn; it wasn't my project to start, but it's now getting assigned to me, and the people who started it aren't super available for discussions like this.

Also, modifying CreateNewUser.php is helpful for after the form is submitted, but I'm looking for how to dynamically generate part of the Register.vue page for the user to see. I'll take a look at the middleware, but editing middleware for a single page feels like overkill.
